# The second part in Schwarz lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f \in \mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D})$, with $f(\mathbb{D}) \subset \mathbb{D}$, such that $f(0) = 0$ and $|f'(0)| = 1$. Prove that exists $\lambda \in \partial \mathbb{D}$ such that $f(z) = \lambda z$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function
$$g(z)=\begin{cases}
f(z)/z & z\ne 0\\
0& z=0
\end{cases}, $$
then $|f'(0)|=1$ implies $|g(z)|=1$. Thus maximum modulus principal shows that $g$ must be a constant $\lambda$ with $|\lambda|=1$. Therefore $f(z)=\lambda z$.

Comment: Why can you deduce $|g(z)| = 1$ from $|f'(0)| = 1$?

Comment: We just use the definition of derivation of $f$ at $z=0$.

Comment: I think from $\lim_{z \to a} A(z) = l$ you can't decuce that $A(z) = l$.

Comment: $f'(0)=\lim_{z\to0}(f(z)-f(0))(z-0)=\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)/z =\lim_{z\to 0}g(z)$.

Comment: Now there is at most one $z$ for which $|g(z)|=1$.

Comment: Your definition 0f $g(0)$ is not correct ! It should read $g(0)=f'(0)$.

Comment: @Fred I think that too.

Comment: @Fred I think that too, too!!! I apologize about bad my type